# Determine whether member class is nested or inner?

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose I have a class that contains come member classes, some of them nested (static) and some inner (non-static):

```
class Foo {
    static class A {}
    class B {}
    static class C {}
}
```

I would like to get all the nested member classes of `Foo`, i.e. `A` and `C`, but not `B`. Is this even possible? I know how to list all the member classes (using `Foo.class.getDesclaredClasses()`), i see methods such as `isLocalClass()`, `isMemberClass()` or `isAnonymousClass()` on `java.lang.Class`, but I don't see anything like `isNested()` or `isInner()`.

Comment: They are as good as class or member variables for Foo. You can write getter for accessing them.

Comment: don't edit your post that invalidate answers as well. add it as EDIT section if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Modifier#isStatic(int mod)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isStatic(int)) (*Return true if the integer argument includes the static modifier, false otherwise.*) to know if the inner-class is static or not.

Like this :

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class foo = Foo.class;
    Class[] declaredClasses = foo.getDeclaredClasses();
    for (Class class1 : declaredClasses) {
        System.out.println(Modifier.isStatic(class1.getModifiers()));
    }
}
}

class Foo {
    static class A {}
    class B {}
    static class C {}
}
```

#### Output :

```
true
false
true
```

**Note :** [`Class#getModifiers()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModifiers()) -

> Returns the Java language modifiers for this class or interface,
>   encoded in an integer. The modifiers consist of the Java Virtual
>   Machine's constants for public, protected, private, final, static,
>   abstract and interface; they should be decoded using the methods of
>   class Modifier.